# gradle build error while adding my lenovo android device

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

this is the error.

Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+.
>        Required by:
>            MyApplication2:app:unspecified
>   Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.+.
>   Failed to list versions for com.android.support:appcompat-v7.
>   Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml.
>   Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/maven-metadata.xml'.
>   jcenter.bintray.com

please help...

Comment: Did you update your SDK Manager?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this line in the dependencies tab under the app tab in studio.
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.0.+'

And,finally it worked for me.